# How to get a Random Non Final variable inside a Final runnable ? -Android

Tags: android, random, time, colors

Can't explain this before showing the code, so :

```
final int randomcolor = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256),
                rnd.nextInt(256));


    final Runnable updater = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {


                    relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(randomcolor);     

                    handler.postDelayed(this, 25);
                }
            }
        };
```

Above I have a runnable named Updater... and below I'm starting it up on a button click..

```
Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            handler.postDelayed(updater,2000 );

        }
    });
```

(I've cut out most of my code so this may not make sense why I want to do this. The above will create an infinite loop as the runnable is stuck with no way out... Just assume that I can get out of it.)

***Explaination of the code***

ALL this is in Oncreate()...
So, on a button click I'm starting up a Runnable after a delay of two seconds...  and then, after every 25 millisecond gap the same runnable is running again and again till the end of time( Like I said, ignore this last point.)

You will see I'm doing only one thing in the runnable, changing the background color of the relative layout.

***Important***, what I want is that after every 25 milliseconds, ie., everytime the runnable runs, It should change the relative Layout's background color to something random. It will probably look like a drunkard flashy epilepsy inducing app... Leave the reason to me (again)

The problem is, the handler can't take a non-final runnable... and a random variable for every run can't be final and final and non-final don't work together.
(read it again)

So, I need a new Color integer everytime the runnable runs...So that every time it runs, it changes the background color to something different and random.

I feel the solution is quite simple, but I can't seem to pin it down..

Any ideas people? How I might go about doing this ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution, even though it might not be the most efficient one, is to generate the color within the runnable itself like so:

```
final Runnable updater = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        final int randomcolor = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256),
            rnd.nextInt(256));
        relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(randomcolor);     
        handler.postDelayed(this, 25);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel dirty for telling you this, but you can wrap your variable in an array or a list.

```
final int[] randomColorHack = new int[1]; 
final Runnable updater = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                  randomColorHack[0] = 100;
            }
        }
    };

int out = randomColorHack[0];

// out == 0;
// until your updater is ran then it will == 100;
```

and obviously if you wanted runnables or a list:

```
 final List<Runnable> hackRunnable = new ArrayList<Runnable>();
 hackRunnable.put(updater);

 Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
           handler.postDelayed(hackRunnable.get(0), 2000);
    }
 }
```

Comment: 25 milliseconds - per run ... That's 40 variable for one sec... If the user is not having seizures... The app will XD  I did try it out, but it's a little too heavy for my app :-)